# Create categories column names from one column in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g

I have oracle table which looks like this:

```
ID---Date------------Type
1  |  01/01/2013  | Install Date 
1  |  05/01/2013  | Complete Date 
1  |  10/01/2013  | Closed Date
2  |  02/01/2013  | Install Date
2  |  03/02/2013  | Closed Date
3  |  10/01/2013  | Install Date
3  |  13/01/2013  | Closed Date
4  |  07/01/2013  | Install Date
4  |  09/01/2013  | Complete Date
4  |  17/01/2013  | Closed Date
```

What I want to achieve is to query this to get result like this:

```
ID--InstallDate--CompleteDate--ClosedDate------
1 | 01/01/2013 | 05/01/2013 | 10/01/2013 
2 | 02/01/2013 | --null-----| 03/02/2013
3 | 10/01/2013 | --null-----| 13/01/2013
4 | 07/01/2013 | 09/01/2013 | 17/01/2013
```

Comment: Do you have a specific issue with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT  ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Install Date' THEN Date END) InstallDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Complete Date' THEN Date END) CompleteDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Closed Date' THEN Date END) ClosedDate
FROM OracleTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively standard pivot query (though the need to do a pivot indicates that the data model is fundamentally problematic).  The old-school approach would be to do something like

```
SELECT id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN type = 'Install Date' THEN dt ELSE null END ) install_date,
       MAX( CASE WHEN type = 'Complete Date' THEN dt ELSE null END ) complete_date,
       MAX( CASE WHEN type = 'Closed Date' THEN dt ELSE null END ) closed_date
  FROM your_table_name
 GROUP BY id
```

Since you're using 11g, you could also use the `PIVOT` operator

```
select *
  from (select id, dt, type 
          from your_table_name)
 pivot (max(dt) as dt FOR (type) in ('Install Date' as install, 
                                     'Complete Date' as complete, 
                                     'Closed Date' as closed))
```